# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: player.mute is not a function

Tags: javascript, dailymotion-api

I add the event listener to the dailymotion playlists. I want to implement the following: When the event catches, get the information about the related playlist and mute it.

```
    // Define the callback function
const callback = (state) => {
    var player = dailymotion.getPlayer(state.id).then((player) => {
    player.mute()
    });
}

// Get access to all embedded player instances on the page
Promise.all(dailymotion.getAllPlayers()).then((players) => {
    // Add an event listener to each player for the 'PLAYER_START' event
    players.forEach((player) => {
        player.on(dailymotion.events.PLAYER_START, callback)
    });
})
```

I get: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: player.mute is not a function

Comment: I don't see "mute" method in the docs.  https://developers.dailymotion.com/sdk/player-sdk/web/#player-methods - try setMute(true) ?

Comment: Try renaming 'player' in (player) to something else ('x' for example). Then do x.mute()

Comment: What's the point of `var player =`? `.then()` returns a promise, not a player.  And you never use the variable anyway.

Comment: You don't need to assign to any variable, there's nothing being returned.

Comment: But it shouldn't cause a problem. The variable is ignored.

Comment: Changing `.mute()` to `.setMute(true)` should be all you needed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried what was proposed by @James and @Barmar:

```
dailymotion.getPlayer(state.id).then((player) => {
   player.setMute(true)
});
```

And that worked.